# How can i find some position near a position?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a position(9,-3). I have a case: I want to print all postion around position(9,-3) and limit in square red line. Because I dont know algorithm looking for all postion around position(9,-3) and limit in square red line. Please help me for some another solutions. Thanks for any solution!

[image]

Like this image:
[image]

Comment: the question is not clear, can you please elaborate with better test cases

Comment: Yes, i have edit it. I have a case: i want to print all postion around position(9,-3)  and limit in square red line. Because i dont know algorithm looking for all postion around position(9,-3)  and limit in square red line. Plz help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var startPoint = {x:5,y:-26};
    var endPoint = {x:13,y:-34};
    var map=[];
    for (i=startPoint.x;i<=endPoint.x;i++) {
        for(j=startPoint.y;j>=endPoint.y;j--) {
            map[i,j] = {x:i,y:j};
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, I code in node js. But i dont know algorithm for solve this case?

Comment: Look on image! And just write it on JS =) But remember CSS: inside border, border, outside border, marging, padding etc.

Comment: Im so sorry, this is example. this is a map. I want to find a algorithm show every every position in distance square red line

Comment: See this code. Or you can pick point on map, set distance. And fill around this point.